# AngularJS and orderBy from Parse data displaying list in an array type format

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am helping a friend build his app in AngularJS and we're using Parse.com as the backend.  I've wired in part of the app to pull from Parse using REST so we can display their Brokers on the 'Find a Broker' page.  It works very well but when ordering the dropdown list to display in alphabetical order, the items are display with each letter in an array format.  Its hard to truly explain, but I'm including a screenshot and a link. Here's the link http://mci.parseapp.com/#/findbroker and here's the screenshot: [image]

Some seriously strange behavior. When I pulled the broker list from a JSON file it displayed correctly, but from Parse, this is what it is doing.

Here's my code:

My Controller (function only):

```
.controller('BrokerCtrl',['$scope','Broker',function($scope,Broker) {
    Broker.getAll().success(function(data){
        $scope.items=data.results;
        $scope.searchFeature = $scope.items[1].MarketArea;
    });
}]);
```

I have a factory setup and named Broker with my Parse info.  Just FYI

And here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Broker Directory</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="orange">
            <strong>Choose a Broker by State</strong>
            <label>
                <select ng-model="searchFeature">
                    <option ng-repeat="broker in items"  ng-selected="broker.MarketArea == searchFeature" value="{{broker.MarketArea}}">{{broker.MarketArea | orderBy:'MarketArea'}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="orange">
            <strong>Name &amp; Location of Broker</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-img-page-2 broker"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div ng-repeat="broker in items | filter:searchFeature" ng-hide="broker.BrokerNum =='000'">
            <p>
                <strong>Market Area:</strong> {{ broker.MarketArea }}<br/>
                {{ broker.BrokerName }}<br/>
                {{ broker.ContactName }}<br/>
                Phone:
                {{ broker.PhoneNum }}<br/>
                Email:
                <a href="mailto:{{ broker.EmailAddress }}">{{ broker.EmailAddress }}</a><br/>
                Web:
                <a href="{{ broker.WebAddress }}">{{ broker.WebAddress }}</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm still developing my Angular chops, so if anyone can help me figure this out, I would be very grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: you are looping on string obviously?

Comment: If I don't order the list, it displays correctly though.  Any ideas what I can do? Thank you.

Comment: use `| orderBy:'MarketArea'` on ng-repeat, not on option text {{ }}

Comment: I feel like a moron...brilliant!! Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put filter on ng-repeat, not when displayed, something like.

```
<option ng-repeat="broker in items | orderBy:'MarketArea'" 
     ng-selected="broker.MarketArea == searchFeature" 
     ng-value="broker.MarketArea">{{broker.MarketArea}} </select>
```